# Save an array from drop-down in custom meta box

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, array

I have successfully pulled a custom post type through into a drop-down that is in a custom meta box. However, when displaying it on the front end I would like to also provide a link to the actual post, not just the name of the post. So I am guessing I need to save this as an array? Is this possible through a drop-down? Confused on how I should approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Add Meta Box To Select Overseeing Pastor
add_action('admin_init', 'ministry_select_add_meta');
function ministry_select_add_meta(){
    add_meta_box('ministry_select_post', __('Overseeing Pastor'), 'ministry_select_meta', 'ministry', 'side');
}

function ministry_select_meta( $post ) {
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $selected = isset( $values['pastor_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['pastor_select'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
        <select name="pastor_select">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'employee',
                'position' => 'pastor'
            );
            $pastorList = new WP_Query($args); while ($pastorList->have_posts()) : $pastorList->the_post();
                $is_selected = (get_the_title() == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option value="'.get_the_title().'" '.$is_selected.'>'.get_the_title().'</option>';
            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </select>
    <?php   
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'ministry_select_save' );
function ministry_select_save( $post_id )
{
    // Stop If Autosaving
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // Stop If Nonce Can't Be Verified
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // Stop If Unauthorized User
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Make Sure Data Is Set Then Save      
    if( isset( $_POST['pastor_select'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'pastor_select', esc_attr( $_POST['pastor_select'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple. Instead of saving the post title, save the post ID, so in the front end you can extract all necessary info.
Like so: [`get_post( $the_saved_ID_value );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) or [`get_permalink( $the_saved_ID_value );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

In you code, change this line:

```
echo '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'" '.$is_selected.'>'.get_the_title().'</option>';
```

Notes:

- Using a `WP_Query` seems a bit too much, consider [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts). Lots of good examples for [**`add_meta_box`**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=add_meta_box%20is%3aanswer).
- Instead of `get_post_custom`, check [**`get_post_meta`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing but forgot to post it. Appreciate the answer! Thanks.